# Join two tables and subtract multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I am brand new to SQL. I am trying to join two tables and subtract column values from table_a from similar columns in table_b in MySQL. The column headings and row headings are identical in both tables.

Example:

```
Table_a
Id_num   Val1   Val2   Val3
nameA       10     20     30
nameB       40     50     60

Table_b
Id_num   Val1   Val2   Val3
nameA       20     35     50
nameB       60     65     85
```

What I want is a table that looks like this:

```
Id_num   Val1   Val2   Val3
nameA       10     15     20
nameB       20     15     25
```

I've tried the following:

```
    SELECT Table_a.Id_num
         (Table_a.Val1 - Table_b.Val1) as Val1,
         (Table_a.Val2 - Table_b.Val2) as Val2,
         (Table_a.Val3 - Table_b.Val3) as Val3
    FROM Table_a
    INNER JOIN Table_a on Table_a.Id_num = Table_b.Id_num;
```

All I can get from this is a syntax error that tells me that 'Table_a' is not a unique table/alias.

I am completely confused. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Table_a inner join table_a -> is this your typing wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Nowhere in my example did I type a lower case "t" for Table_a?

Comment: Look careful in code block of your post "FROM Table_a INNER JOIN Table_a". I think it is your typing mistake but If you really write code like this It is a big error. One more thing, I see answer below is quite good and it may be correct answer for you

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a coma in your `SELECT` and your `join` should be on Table_b

```
 SELECT Table_a.Id_num,
         (Table_a.Val1 - Table_b.Val1) as Val1,
         (Table_a.Val2 - Table_b.Val2) as Val2,
         (Table_a.Val3 - Table_b.Val3) as Val3
    FROM Table_a
    INNER JOIN Table_b on Table_b.Id_num = Table_a.Id_num;
```